# 'Vox Populi' badges being awarded mistakenly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This issue is a big one on SO meta right now:

[Vox Populi, Civic Duty, and Electorate badges being awarded en masse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123159/vox-populi-civic-duty-and-electorate-badges-being-awarded-en-masse)

I wasn't sure if posting here was a duplicate, but it should be noted that this is happening in Gaming.SE as a result of the change that causes this.  I've just earned the badge, and haven't made a single vote today.

Comment: I just figured they were belatedly realizing that my votes carry the importance of 10 normal votes.

Comment: @Sterno I guess we can't all be Jon Skeet...

Comment: @Anna Status-bydesign is kind of confusing because the question title is specifically about "Vox Populi", which did indeed have a bug that has now been addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the MSO post linked to, we just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there was a bug with Vox Populi only that awarded too many of them (beyond the expected more for retroactive awards) and a fix has been deployed.  The erroneous awards have been cleaned up.

Comment: Just to be clear... this issue is still being worked on as of the time of this comment, right?  My profile says I've only made 5 total votes, when I've definitely made at least 10 times that.

Comment: Are you looking at your meta profile instead of your main user profile?

Comment: Ah, duh, yes I was.  It threw me off that my rep from Gaming.SE is shown at the top (is there a separate meta.gaming rep?).

Comment: @John No. Only Meta SO has separate rep.

Comment: I tought you coudn't vote more than 30 times for day - still, i won one right now for casting 40 votes. Weird.